# React Native - Why using the && operator in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am learning to `StyleSheet` api and found the following expression in this [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet):

```
<Text style={[styles.title, this.props.isActive && styles.activeTitle]} />
```

Can anyone tell what is this `&&` operator used for inside the array? A little example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

Comment: It's part of the expression `this.props.isActive && styles.activeTitle` and it does exactly the same thing it'd do outside of an array initializer. If `this.props.isActive` evaluates to something not truthy, then that's the value that's put in the array; otherwise the array gets the value of `styles.activeTitle`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This form takes advantage of [operator short circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation).

If `this.props.isActive` yields `true`, then the value of `this.props.isActive && styles.activeTitle` will be `styles.activeTitle`.

In the opposite case, if `this.props.isActive` is "falsy" (coerced to false in boolean context), the expression will short-circuit and yield `this.props.isActive`.

The `style` parameter in React Native can take an array of style objects that are merged. A false value will be skipped*, so if `!isActive`, then the style parameter will simply become `styles.title`.

(*Merge is probably done using `Object.assign` which will copy only enumerable and own properties, and will not throw on falsy values; but I don't know this for sure. Does someone?)

Comment: `The style parameter in React can take an array of style objects that are merged.` This is wrong, this documentation says that the `the last style in the array has precedence` so which means that the last styling object will be applied. Now who is right, you or documentation? Documentation link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting what that passage means. "Last style ... has precedence" means in practice that if you have `fontSize: 12` in the first object and `fontSize: 16` in the second, the last one wins.

Comment: @PurpleBytes you absolutely can pass a an array of style objects to the style property, and they absolutely are merged. I'm not sure why you're being condescending but I can assure you that you are incorrect

Comment: @Sami Hult - no i did check and pass two object  ids in the array and i don't use any `fontSize` and i just use the color property in both objects but the last one in the array wins. Even i use the `fontSize` property, still the last one in the array wins !!! Please do check

Comment: Try to pass `[ { color: 'blue', fontSize: 100 }, { color: 'black' } ]` to see that they are, in fact, merged.

Comment: Check it by yourself this is the prove: `const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  red: {
    fontSize: 60
  },
  blue : {
    fontSize: 30
  }
});` and `<Text style={[styles.red,styles.blue]}>Some Text</Text>`

Comment: This discussion has derailed: it is outside the scope of the original question, which was about `&&` operator. If you think I'm wrong here, please provide a complete and verifiable example that proves me wrong.

Comment: I just added the `fontSize` to the last styling object to your example ,so the last one wins look `style={[{ color: 'blue', fontSize: 100 }, { color: 'black', fontSize: 20 }]}`

Comment: Yes, they are merged with the last one having precedence. If you drop `color: 'black'` from your last example, you will see that `color: 'blue'` is retained, but `fontSize` will change.

Comment: We both are right at our own sense, but the RN logic for the array of styling objects is strange. Anyways thanks !!!